# Lendo arquivos .CAP de forma eficiente com Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, segurança, redes, ip

Tenho alguns arquivos .CAP originados de captura de pacotes com tcpdump. Ao tentar abrir com wireshark, a máquina fica muito lenta, pois imagino que ele tente carregar tudo para a memória RAM.

Gostaria de escrever um programa em Python para trabalhar de forma mais eficiente com os dumps. A primeira dúvida é: qual a diferença entre .CAP e .PCAP?

Eu não preciso ler o arquivo inteiro de uma vez. Imagine que queira ler o arquivo .CAP apenas do tempo(hora) = 9h15 até 11h12 , em vez de carregá-lo inteiro na memória. Como fazer isso em Python? Lembrando que os arquivos são .CAP e não .PCAP.

Segue a saida de: "tcpdump -r /caminho/para/ficehiro.cap | less"

```
09:32:20.107281 IP iskcon.interactivedns.com.http > 192.168.91.34.47651: Flags [S.], seq 63
8820025, ack 2476676485, win 28960, options [mss 1380,sackOK,TS val 3245680284 ecr 42949413
64,nop,wscale 7], length 0
09:32:20.107308 IP 192.168.91.34.47651 > iskcon.interactivedns.com.http: Flags [.], ack 1, 
win 229, options [nop,nop,TS val 4294941466 ecr 3245680284], length 0
09:32:20.107357 IP 192.168.91.34.47651 > iskcon.interactivedns.com.http: Flags [P.], seq 1:
181, ack 1, win 229, options [nop,nop,TS val 4294941466 ecr 3245680284], length 180: HTTP: 
GET / HTTP/1.1
09:32:20.144075 IP ec2-52-73-252-184.compute-1.amazonaws.com.http > 192.168.91.34.47570: Fl
ags [.], seq 831563414:831564782, ack 387706135, win 75, options [nop,nop,TS val 499391566 
ecr 4294941090], length 1368: HTTP
09:32:20.144094 IP 192.168.91.34.47570 > ec2-52-73-252-184.compute-1.amazonaws.com.http: Fl
ags [.], ack 1368, win 816, options [nop,nop,TS val 4294941475 ecr 499391566], length 0
09:32:20.144368 IP ec2-52-73-252-184.compute-1.amazonaws.com.http > 192.168.91.34.47570: Fl
ags [.], seq 1368:2736, ack 1, win 75, options [nop,nop,TS val 499391566 ecr 4294941090], l
ength 1368: HTTP
09:32:20.144376 IP 192.168.91.34.47570 > ec2-52-73-252-184.compute-1.amazonaws.com.http: Fl
ags [.], ack 2736, win 838, options [nop,nop,TS val 4294941475 ecr 499391566], length 0
09:32:20.145197 IP ec2-52-73-252-184.compute-1.amazonaws.com.http > 192.168.91.34.47570: Fl
ags [.], seq 2736:4104, ack 1, win 75, options [nop,nop,TS val 499391566 ecr 4294941090], l
ength 1368: HTTP
09:32:20.145204 IP 192.168.91.34.47570 > ec2-52-73-252-184.compute-1.amazonaws.com.http: Fl
ags [.], ack 4104, win 861, options [nop,nop,TS val 4294941475 ecr 499391566], length 0
09:32:20.145214 IP ec2-52-73-252-184.compute-1.amazonaws.com.http > 192.168.91.34.47570: Fl
ength 1368: HTTP
09:32:20.145218 IP 192.168.91.34.47570 > ec2-52-73-252-184.compute-1.amazonaws.com.http: Fl
ags [.], ack 5472, win 883, options [nop,nop,TS val 4294941475 ecr 499391566], length 0
09:32:20.148032 IP ec2-52-73-252-184.compute-1.amazonaws.com.http > 192.168.91.34.47570: Fl
ags [.], seq 5472:6840, ack 1, win 75, options [nop,nop,TS val 499391566 ecr 4294941090],
```

[image: imagem de outro arquivo CAP]

Consumo de memoria do wireshark ao abrir um CAP de 1GB:

[image: memoria wireshark]

Comment: Experimenta "tcpdump -r /caminho/para/ficehiro.cap | less" no terminal

Comment: Obrigado @Miguel. Preciso que seja em Python, pois irei processar o arquivo depois!

Comment: podes colocar um exemplo do formato interno do ficheiro, as primeiras 10 linhas por ex: "head -10 ficheiro.cap" no terminal sff

Comment: Caro @Miguel, head -10 arquivo.cap -> a saida foram caracteres estranhos. O comando é esse mesmo?  usei do terminal do Ubuntu

Comment: é para imprimir as primeiras 10 linhas de um ficheiro

Comment: @Miguel:�ò���T�X�JJ�H���g��E<@*�ϋ�
���["P�#&������q zd
�u&�����T�X,�BB�g����H��E4@@����["��
��#P���&����Y
����u&�T�X]����g����H��E�@@����["��
��#P���&�����!
����u&�GET / HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Fedora; Linux x86_64; rv:50.1.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/50.1.0
Accept: */*
Host: www.iskconbangalore.org

Comment: http://www.linfo.org/head.html. Talvez isto ajude: https://www.google.pt/search?client=ms-android-huawei&ei=Jy63WL2mGYmtU7Kho4gC&q=read+cap+file+with+python&oq=read+cap+file+with+python&gs_l=mobile-gws-serp.12...13514.14049.0.15132.4.4.0.0.0.0.291.702.0j3j1.4.0....0...1c.1j4.64.mobile-gws-serp..1.0.0.YXLkOL3WsaI

Comment: Vou tentar fazer um print do wireshark (arquivo aberto) e postar o link.

Comment: Mais de 30 minutos carregando no wireshark. O dump tem 2.6 GB

Comment: O melhor é seguires-te por https://www.google.pt/search?client=ms-android-huawei&ei=Jy63WL2mGYmtU7Kho4gC&q=read+cap+file+with+python&oq=read+cap+file+with+python&gs_l=mobile-gws-serp.12...13514.14049.0.15132.4.4.0.0.0.0.291.702.0j3j1.4.0....0...1c.1j4.64.mobile-gws-serp..1.0.0.YXLkOL3WsaI, por ex:  https://jon.oberheide.org/blog/2008/10/15/dpkt-tutorial-2-parsing-a-pcap-file/. Nunca trabalhei com isto, acho que não vou conseguir ajudar-te nisto

Comment: @Miguel:  Coloquei a saida de tcpdump -r /caminho/para/ficehiro.cap | less na pergunta.

Comment: @Miguel: coloquei a imagem de outro arquivo CAP

Comment: Aparentemente o Wireshark tem sua própria API para integração via Lua: https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsdg_html_chunked/wsluarm_modules.html Ou seja, talvez Python não seja o melhor pra vc. :)

Comment: dá uma olhada na minha resposta, isso vai te ajudar a processar aquivos gigantes...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eu só vi essa pergunta agora, a forma eficiente é abrir o arquivo em pedaços, com a ajuda de ponteiros é possível definir a posição de inicio e fim de leitura de um arquivo, em `python` não é possível manipular ponteiros de memória diretamente, para a nossa sorte a função `open`(essa função deve estar escrita em C) do python internamente manipula ponteiros que nos ajuda no processo de leitura de arquivos, com ela é possível definir a abertura de um arquivo por tamanho em bytes, ou seja é possível abrir o aquivo pedaço por pedaço (a cada byte) sem precisar abrir o arquivo inteiro, veja como é feito:

```
from scapy.all import *
import dpkt

f = open("capture21dez2016.pcap")


pcap = f.read(4096)
while pcap:

    #processe cada pedaço aqui

    pcap = f.read(4096)

f.close()
```

O exemplo abre o arquivo a cada 4096 bytes de dados e percorre todo o arquivo até o fim dele, é uma maneira de não estourar a memória por falta de recursos, muito útil quando você tem que caminhar por arquivos gigantes, a função `f.read()` sabe qual foi a posição do último ponteiro e começa a ler os próximos bytes a partir da ultima posição conhecida.

Você ainda pode iniciar a leitura de um arquivo a partir de uma determinada posição usando o `seek` muito útil quando você precisa iniciar uma leitura a partir de um determinado byte veja um exemplo:

arquivo.txt

```
A
B
C
D
E
F
G
H
I
J
```

cada `enter` é equivalente a `2bytes=\n` ou seja 1 byte para a `\` e outro byte para o `n`, para exemplificar e se eu quiser ler o `arquivo.txt` começando do `byte=3`?

```
>>> f = open('arquivo.txt', 'r+')
>>> f.seek(3)
>>> f.read(1)
'B'
```

O  `seek(3)` diz para onde apontar, neste caso posicione o ponteiro no terceiro byte e o `read(1)` diz para ler `1byte` de dado a partir da posição apontada.

Ai você me pergunta por que o terceiro byte é igual a letra `B`? lembra que o enter equivale a `2bytes` portando a primeira linha é como se fosse:

```
A\n = 3bytes
```

Ou seja a letra `B` do arquivo vai estar no `byte=4` que foi o que fizemos, apontamos a leitura para começar no `byte=3` e mandamos ler o próximo `1 byte`

E se eu quiser a letra `F`?

Partindo do mesmo principio e contando os caracteres e os enters, a letra `F` Vai estar no `byte=16`, para posicionar o ponteiro e chegar nele é assim:

```
>>> f.seek(15)
>>> f.read(1)
'F'
```

Para um arquivo de texto corrido sem `enter`:

arquivo2.txt

```
KLMNOPQRS
```

Se eu quiser a letra do quinto byte:

```
>>> f = open('arquivo2.txt', 'r+')
>>> f.seek(4)
>>> f.read(1)
'O'
```

E se eu quiser o arquivo inteiro a partir do quinto byte?

```
>>> f.seek(4)
>>> f.read()
'OPQRS'
```

E se eu quiser caminhar no arquivo de trás pra frente ? você pode setar o parâmetro `2` no `seek(X,2)` isso indica que ele vai caminhar iniciando do final do arquivo.

```
>>> f.seek(-6,2)
>>> f.read(1)
'N'
```

Com esses conceito você vai poder manipular e caminhar de forma eficiente dentro de arquivos gigantes...

Agora tudo o que tem que fazer é abrir o arquivo em pedaços ou iniciar de um determinado lugar e ir comparando quais linhas estão dentro do intervalo desejado, depois de armazenar os dados termine o loop com um `break`, dessa maneira é bem provável que não precise caminhar pelo arquivo inteiro, a não ser que os dados desejado estejam na ultima linha do arquivo, e  mesmo assim você pode criar alguma artimanha para saber se deve inciar a leitura do arquivo do inicio ou do fim dele.

Comment: muito obrigado. vou estudar com calma e volto para marcar a resposta!

Comment: scapy funciona 100% em python 3?

Comment: tentei adaptar o meu codigo aqui:  http://imgur.com/aMqxn3H

Erros:
http://imgur.com/a/QybqX

Comment: Eu preciso separar em arquivos texto diferentes os IP de origem e destino para posteriormente calcular a entropia!

Comment: vc de alguma maneira tem que pegar os pedaços de dados e passar para  o dpkt.pcap.Reader nao é isso? ele coloca no formato de leitura que você quer, não tenho como testar isso aqui...

Comment: nao tem que usar algum decode? pergunto pq o pcap = f1.read(4096) é string!

Comment: é o que o pcap.Reader faz não é? ele faz o decode, isso é com vc, eu acredo que depois de cada linha pcap = f.read(4096) você teria que fazer pcap_convertido=dpkt.pcap.Reader(pcap)

Comment: consegui fazer de outro jeito também, o que acha? http://imgur.com/a/gMY4m

Comment: o consumo de RAM caiu de 97/98% para cerca de 20%. VOcê vê algum problema no código?

Comment: agradeço a sua solucao também! Antes, com um PCAP de  500MB mesmo, o consumo de RAM já batia 97%. Meu laptop tem 8 GB de RAM...

Comment: este código é parte de um projeto acadêmico de pesquisa. Agradeço muito a sua contribuição! Estou rodando agora o algoritmo em todos os dumps para depois lotar os gráficos das entropias! Obrigado

Answer (score 2):

Para facilitar simulei um arquivo do tipo .cap, criando um arquivo texto cap1.cap onde cada linha tem somente os primeiros caracteres (que indicam o horario), de acordo com o que voce postou aqui. Ficou assim:

09:32:20.107281

09:32:20.107357

09:32:21.144075

09:32:21.144094

09:32:21.144368

09:33:21.144376

09:34:21.145197

09:35:00.145204

09:36:20.145214

09:36:20.145218

09:37:20.148032

Depois desenvolvi um codigo para ler esse arquivo e "printar" somente as linhas entre os horários: 09:32:21 e 09:35:00, fiz o teste e ocorreu como esperado, acredito que com algumas adaptações vc resolve seu problema. Codigo abaixo.

```
import datetime
import re

inicio = datetime.datetime.strptime('09:32:21', '%H:%M:%S').time()
fim = datetime.datetime.strptime('09:35:00', '%H:%M:%S').time()

startprint = False
with open('cap1.cap', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        str_begin = line[:8]
        if re.match(r'^[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]$', str_begin) != None:
            t = datetime.datetime.strptime(str_begin, '%H:%M:%S').time()
            startprint = True
        if startprint:    
           if t>fim:
               break
           if t>=inicio and t<=fim:
               print (line)
```

Resultado:

09:32:21.144075

09:32:21.144094

09:32:21.144368

09:33:21.144376

09:34:21.145197

09:35:00.145204

Comment: Veja que de qualquer forma o código primeiro carrega todo o arquivo para a memoria para depois ler linha a linha (não consegui vislumbrar outra forma), sendo assim, não sei se vai ficar mais rapido do que o aplicativo que voce usa.

Comment: Uma tentativa para ganhar velocidade em python seria a utilização do  [cython](http://cython.org/)